# Get activity context and button position inside OnClickListener inside ExpandableListAdapter

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, android-imagebutton

I want to different things depending on the current activity of the app and button position inside the expandable list.

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

   private Context _context;
   private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
   // child data in format of header title, child title
   private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

   ImageButton downloadButton = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
            downloadButton.setFocusable(false);
            downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //CODE}
            });
```

I tried ExpandableListAdapter.this.getClass().getSimpleName() but it's not working.

EDIT: Full class:

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
private int itemtype;


public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData,int itemtype) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    this.itemtype=itemtype;

}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);



    if (itemtype == 1) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_child_disciplinas, null);



            ImageButton downloadButton = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloadButton);
            downloadButton.setFocusable(false);
            downloadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //CODE


                }
            });




        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lista_child_disciplinas);


        txtListChild.setText(childText);

    }
    else {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_child, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lista_child);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);

    }


    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_parent, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lista_parent);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Provide your full adapter `class`. I need to see which is what??

Comment: @Wizard done :)

Comment: You have your position in `getView()` method as an arguments, that are `int groupPosition, final int childPosition,`